# i want to show details on same page

Tags: reactjs, api, frontend

i am developing an application i.e supply chain management application on reactJS, NodeJS and blockchain.
Frontend code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



const SignUp = () =>  {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
 const flag=0;
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        uname: "",
        email: "",
        location: "",
        budget: "",
        password: ""
      });
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setData({
          ...data,
          [e.target.name]: value
        });
      };
    
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
          
            uname: data.uname,
            email: data.email,
            location: data.location,
            budget: data.budget,
            password: data.password
        };
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup/", userData)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
              console.log(error.response);
              console.log("server responded");
            } else if (error.request) {
              console.log("network error");
            } else {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
          navigate(`/home`)
   

      };
      

  
    return (
      <form>
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>User Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="uname" 
            value={data.uname}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="User name"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email" 
            value={data.email}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>Location</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="location" 
            value={data.location}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Location"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>Budget</label>
          <input
            type="Number"
            name="budget" 
            value={data.budget}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Budget"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password" 
            value={data.password}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="d-grid">
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}className="btn btn-primary">
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </div>
        <p className="forgot-password text-right">
          Already registered <a href="/sign-in">sign in?</a>
        </p>
      </form>
    );
    
};
export default SignUp;
```

[image: here is the page]

here if user successfully registered then i want to show deatils of the user on the same page. how should i do that?
i have attached the code and the screenshot of the page.
currently i am on my account page.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your handle submit
You can just navigate after the `axios.then` callback

Or if you want the behavior to be that user submits -> register success -> show success -> then redirect, you can setTimeout for say 1000ms and then navigate.

```js
axios
          .post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup/", userData)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => navigate(`/home`), 1000);
          }
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
              console.log(error.response);
              console.log("server responded");
            } else if (error.request) {
              console.log("network error");
            } else {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, show the user data after a successful registration and assuming you're calling an api to register the user and you're getting the user details back on success, you can handle that in your `handleSubmit` method.

Here's an example

```js
const showUserDetails = (userDetails) => {
// Code that shows user details
// Probably using state
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
          ...
      axios
          .post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup/", userData)
          .then((response) => {
             // handle here
             showUserDetails(response);
          })
         

          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
              ...
            } else {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });

      };
```